# How to show/hide a td tag after hiding it

Tags: javascript, html

I hide a td tag but I cant show it afterwards so I wonder what is that problem.

I draw the td tag by using javascript and when the user select option in the dropdown list which class is `selected_option` will decide the visibility of it.

The problem is the td cant be hide or shown even though I changed the selected option.

```
tempHtml += '<td id="lang-capvariable"><input type="text" class="w3-input"></td>';

$('.selected_option').change(function(){
     let option = $(this).val()
     let showvariable=false;

     switch(option){
          case(show):
              showvariable=true;
              break;
          case(hide):
              showvariable=false;
              break;
          default:
              showvariable=false;
              break;
     }

     if(showvariable==true){
          $('#lang-capvariable').show()
     }else{
          $('#lang-capvariable').hide()
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you remove the `hidden` attribute from TD and just rely on JS for hiding and showing?

Comment: Where are you drawing the tag? You're just appending to the `tempHtml` variable, not appending to the DOM. What are the values of the `show` and `hide` variables? Your code is also missing some closing braces (`}`). Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72655787/edit) to fix your code.

Comment: `$('#lang-capvariable').prop('hidden', false);` to show it, and `$('#lang-capvariable').prop('hidden', true);` to hide it. The `show`/`hide` methods hide an element through the `display` property.

Comment: @kmoser in order to make my question clear and simple I omitted those variables and other code that are nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Your `if(showvariable==true){ ... }` block needs to be *inside* the event handler. As you have it written now, the `if()` executes once and only once when the page loads, but not when the dropdown changes.

Comment: What are the values of the `show` and `hide` variables? Your code example above is incomplete, and not sufficient for us to help you. Please edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show all table

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td id=ChangeMe>0</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
<button id=ShowHide>Show / Hide</button>
<script src=Code.js></script>
```

Code.js

```
 function ChangeVisibility()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("ChangeMe").style.display=='none')
        {
            document.getElementById("ChangeMe").style.display='block';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("ChangeMe").style.display='none';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("ShowHide").addEventListener("click",ChangeVisibility);

ChangeVisibility();
```

Load javascript and hide td element in the end of javascript if you need to start width hidden td.